# Collection for storing objects and quick retrieving?

Tags: java, collections

I want to collection some objects within an application. I need a Collection that can give me an object by `list.get(object)` so that I can write functions like:

```
List<Object> list;

getProperty(Object o) {
  list.get(o).getProperty();
}
```

What is most suitable for this?

Comment: Like an **ArrayList**? **LinkedList**? Suitable for what?

Comment: suitable for retrieving an object by `get(object)`. Does not matter which type of list...

Comment: Just what do you expect `get(object)` to return? The object you give as parameter? (Then why not call `getProperty` on it directly?) Some other object? (Then you do not want a collection, but a map. `HashMap` will most likely do.)

Comment: OK HashMap seems suitable! I was just getting confused by all those type of collections that I could not see which would be suitable.